# Does Matlab support multiple access of a function at the same time?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, function

I have a situation in Matlab where a function "A" might be accessed at the same time (simultaneously) by 2 other functions. From what I know, for this to work, Matlab should make 2 seperate copies and handle them seperately, known as a thread save feature. Does Matlab support this? I have the 2012a version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I frequently use the same function simultaneously from multiple matlab instances.
Also I sometimes call the same function numerous times via recursion.

Therefore it is definately possible to call the same function twice.

Each time you call the function a local workspace will be created.

Comment: Note that I am not talking about cases where you: have global variables, use multithreading, create a mex file or compile certain kinds of code. As long as you just have normal functions you should be fine.